# Complex switch Case SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am stuck in a complex SQL switch case statement in the midst of a stored procedure.

I am copying the middle part of the stored procedure:

```
AND 
( 
  @Statuses IS NULL 
  OR 
  [BF].[BookingFileStatusID] IN 
  ( 
         SELECT [ID] 
         FROM   @BookingFileStatuses) 
  AND 
  ( 
    @Statuses IS NULL 
    OR 
    **(( 
    ( 
           SELECT count([ID]) 
           FROM   @BookingFileStatuses) >= 1) 
    AND 
    ( 
      1 = ( 
      CASE 
      WHEN [S].servicetypeid IS NULL THEN 1 
      WHEN ( 
          [S].servicetypeid <> 3 
          AND 
          [BF].bookingfilestatusid IN ( 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23) 
        ) 
        THEN 1 
      WHEN ( 
          [S].servicetypeid = 3 
          AND 
          [BF].bookingfilestatusid IN 
          ( 
                 SELECT [ID] 
                 FROM   @BookingStatuses) 
        ) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END) 
    ) 
    )** 
  ) 
)
```

Highlighted portion should return some results.

i.e. replace the highlighted portion with if else.

Please assist.

Comment: You didn't explain your problem. Please clarify what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @Mikuana : Applying the proper case .
Have to replace the xxxxxxxxxxxxxx with the aforementioned statement , which is returning true or false

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)?  Without sample data, and expected outcomes to test against, this kind of question can be very hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the whole thing without the case statement. It is easier to read this way.

```
(
     (SELECT Count([ID]) FROM @BookingFileStatuses) >= 1
AND 
   (     [S].ServiceTypeID IS  NULL 
      OR  ([S].ServiceTypeID <> 3 AND [BF].BookingFileStatusID in (16,17,18,19,20,23)) 
      OR  ([S].ServiceTypeID = 3 AND [BF].BookingFileStatusID in (SELECT [ID] FROM @BookingStatuses)) 
   )
)
```

Comment: It is giving me syntactical error.
I have edited my question.Please have a look at it .

Answer (score 0):

In this part :

```
 AND ( @Statuses IS NULL 
    OR  
    1 = (CASE WHEN @BookingStatusCount = 0  THEN 1                      

    ELSE 
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    END)    

)
```

you are making Or with two cases : 1=( 1 or sth else). so you don't need the second query at all. because alway you can make one value. I would like to write this:

```
 AND ( @Statuses IS NULL 
        OR  
       1 = (CASE WHEN @BookingStatusCount = 0  THEN 1  else 5)    
     )
```

Comment: This is the part of logic , which cannot be ignored

Comment: but it is useless . this select count(*) always returns a value .right? for example 1-2-3-0 any thing so with compare by 1 =(0||1 or anything)

Comment: Could you please see the updated question.
I have to update the highlighted portion in if and else condition